# How to show the image uploaded using HTML file control on a new page after form submission in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, image-upload

I've a form which contains following file upload control and image control:

```
<form action="rebate_preview.php" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_path" id="hidden_path" value="">
  <input type="file" name="rebate_image" id="rebate_image">
  <img id="rebate_old_image" src="#" alt="your image" width="80" height="80"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here I'm enabling the user to see the preview of the image he selected for upload without actually uploading the image to server using following jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#rebate_old_image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#hidden_path').val(e.target.result)
      }            
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
  $("#rebate_image").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
  });
});
```

Now the problems I'm facing is I'm not able to show the same image preview on the next page i.e. on a file "rebate_preview.php" after form submission using image control. The next issue I'm facing is how should I store the values from array `$_FILES` on the page rebate_preview.php?

Remember still the image uploaded by user is not yet uploaded to the server.

The page rebate_preview.php is just a preview page with some other fields to preview the details.

How should I show this image on the page rebate_preview.php using image control and how should I store the `$_FILES` array data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem a short while back when I was building an application, the best thing to create an OBJECT URL from the selected image when you select the file, you can then set your `img src` to that OBJECT URL data, which will render it to the page, for example lets say you have a file input with the id `image_file`. you could do this:

```
// Preview the image on the page
$('#image_file').change(function(e) {

    var selected_file = $('#image_file').get(0).files[0];
    selected_file = window.URL.createObjectURL(selected_file);
    $('#preview_image').attr('src' , selected_file);

});
```

The source is now the BLOB representation of the image, you can then submit your form to upload the image or select another image to update the preview, hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes man, your idea really worked perfect for me. You saved my life man.Would you please do me another small favour by giving solution to my next problem i.e How should I store the values from array $_FILES on the page rebate_preview.php?

Comment: If when you press submit you are redirected to `rebate_preview.php`  then you should be able to ensure that your `$_FILES` array has been sent to that script by writing `var_dump($_FILES)` you can then transfer the key data from that into variables.  Make sure you do tests to ensure that the array isn't empty or you'll get errors :)

Comment: :Ok,can I store this $_FILES data into hidden field after making testes to check it's emptiness? If I do so then can I get the $_FILES array data as it is after formsubmitting the form on page rebate_preview? Actually my requirement is I should be able to get the $_FILES array data as it is after submission of form on page rebate_preview.php. Can you please guide me in this regard?

Comment: Could you open another question and show me what you require, I'm fairly confused.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution?

in PHP script just do:

```
print "<img src='".$_POST['hidden_path']."'>";
```

Comment: he wants a preview before uploading to the server, so this wouldn't work as nothing yet has been posted?

Comment: Read again: Now the problems I'm facing is I'm not able to show the same image preview on the next page i.e. on a file "rebate_preview.php" after form submission using image control. The next issue I'm facing is how should I store the values from array $_FILES on the page rebate_preview.php?

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry James, your answer should definitely suffice then, upvoted.

Comment: No problem, I also thought he wanted it as a preview on the first page until I copied his code and tried it, and since it worked, I re-read.

Comment: I jumped the gun a little, too used to building applications with minimal redirection :P